# How to solve Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=18; index=18 in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app, In this, I want to save users personal details onbutton click, But when I click on submit button it shows the error i.e  Caused by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=18; index=18. How do I solve this? Please suggest me. Following is my code how do I solve this?.

//code

```
public class MyPersonalDetailsActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

        RadioGroup rgGender, rgDopinion, rgYca, rgPye;
        Button btnSave, btnBdate;
        EditText edFname, edLname, edEmail, edPass, edAddress, edCountry, edState, edBdate, edCity, edMob, edHeight, edWeight, edQualification, edOccupation;
        RadioButton rbYes, rbNo, rbFit, rbUnfit, rbYesa, rbNota, rbMale, rbFemale;
        RadioButton rbGender, rbPye, rbDopinion, rbYca;
        Toolbar toolbar;
        TextView user_id, responsetypes;
        Calendar myCalendar;

        private boolean isLoggedIn = false;
        SessionManagement session;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_personal_details);

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            toolbarTitle.setText("My Personal Details");
            toolbar.setTitleMarginBottom(50);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            user_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_id);
            edFname= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_fname);
            edEmail= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_email);
            edPass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_passowrd);
            edMob= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_mobile);
            edBdate= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_dob);
            edAddress= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_address);
            edCountry= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_country);
            edState= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_state);
            edCity= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_city);
            edHeight= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_height);
            edWeight= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_weight);
            edQualification= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_qaulification);
            edOccupation= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_occupation);

            rgGender= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg_gender);
            rgDopinion= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg_drop);
            rgPye= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg_pye);
            rgYca= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg_yca);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SessionManagement.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SessionManagement.IS_LOGIN, false);
            String email = sharedPreferences.getString(SessionManagement.KEY_EMAIL, "Not Available");
            user_id.setText(email);

            myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    updateLabel();
                }
            };
            edBdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new DatePickerDialog(MyPersonalDetailsActivity1.this, date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                }
            });

            //btnBdate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_bdate);
            btnSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_save) {

                        if (checkValidation()) {

                            int selectedIdGender = rgGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            rbGender = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedIdGender);

                            int selectedIdYca = rgYca.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            rbYca = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedIdYca);

                            int selectedIdPye = rgPye.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            rbPye = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedIdPye);

                            int selectedIdDrop = rgDopinion.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            rbDopinion = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedIdDrop);

                            String firstname1 = edFname.getText().toString();
                            String lastname = null;
                            String emailid = edEmail.getText().toString();
                            String password = edPass.getText().toString();
                            String address1 = edAddress.getText().toString();
                            String country = edCountry.getText().toString();
                            String state = edState.getText().toString();
                            String city = edCity.getText().toString();
                            String contactno = edMob.getText().toString();
                            String sex = rbGender.getText().toString();
                            String height = edHeight.getText().toString();
                            String weight = edWeight.getText().toString();
                            String qualification1 = edQualification.getText().toString();
                            String occupation1 = edOccupation.getText().toString();
                            String pye = rbPye.getText().toString();
                            String dopinion = rbDopinion.getText().toString();
                            String attendcourse = rbYca.getText().toString();
                            String birthdate = edBdate.getText().toString();
                            int userID = 12973;
                            String zipcode = null;

                            try {
                                String firstname = URLEncoder.encode(firstname1, "utf-8");
                                String address = URLEncoder.encode(address1, "utf-8");
                                String qualification = URLEncoder.encode(qualification1, "utf-8");
                                String occupation = URLEncoder.encode(occupation1, "utf-8");

                                System.out.println("Givennames is :" + firstname + " Given password is :" + password + "Gender:" + sex);

                                connectWithHttpGet(firstname, lastname, emailid, password, birthdate, zipcode,
                                        sex, address, country, state, city, contactno,
                                        height, weight, qualification, occupation, pye,
                                        dopinion, attendcourse, userID);

                                if (isLoggedIn) {
                                    //We will start the Profile Activity
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyPersonalDetailsActivity1.this, MenuActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }

                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Toast.makeText(MyPersonalDetailsActivity.this, "Please Fill the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }


        private void connectWithHttpGet(String firstname, String lastname, String emailid, String password, String birthdate,String zipcode,
                                        String sex, String address, String country, String state, String city, String contactno,
                                        String height, String weight, String qualification, String occupation, String pye,
                                        String dopinion, String attendcourse, int userID) {

            class HttpGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    // As you can see, doInBackground has taken an Array of Strings as the argument
                    //We need to specifically get the givenUsername and givenPassword

                    String paramFname = params[0];
                    String paramLname = params[1];
                    String paramEmail = params[2];
                    String paramPassword = params[3];
                    String paramAddress = params[4];
                    String paramCountry = params[5];
                    String paramBirthdate = params[6];
                    String paramZip = params[7];
                    String paramState = params[8];
                    String paramCity = params[9];
                    String paramPhone = params[10];
                    String paramSex = params[11];
                    String paramHeight = params[12];
                    String paramWeight = params[13];
                    String paramQualifn = params[14];
                    String paramDopenion = params[15];
                    String paramPye = params[16];
                    String paramOccupatn = params[17];
                    String paramYca = params[18];
                    String paramUserid = params[19];  //HERE GIVES AN ERROR


                    System.out.println("userID" + paramFname + " email is :" + paramEmail+" gender is :" + paramSex);

                    // Create an intermediate to connect with the Internet
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    // Sending a GET request to the web page that we want
                    // Because of we are sending a GET request, we have to pass the values through the URL
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/ypAndroid/api/SavePersonalDetails?firstname="+paramFname+"&lastname="+null+
                            "&emailid="+paramEmail+"&password="+paramPassword+
                            "&address1="+paramAddress+"&Country="+paramCountry+"&birthdate="+paramBirthdate+"&zipcode="+null+"&state="+paramState+
                            "&city="+paramCity+"&phonenumber="+paramPhone+"&sex="+paramSex+"&heightincms="+paramHeight+"&weightinkgs="+paramWeight+
                            "&qualification="+paramQualifn+"&doctorsopinion="+paramDopenion+"&PreviousYogaExperience="+paramPye+"&business="+paramOccupatn+
                            "&attendcourse="+paramYca+"&userid="+12973);

                    try {
                        // execute(); executes a request using the default context.
                        // Then we assign the execution result to HttpResponse
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                        System.out.println("httpResponse// getEntity() ; obtains the message entity of this response");
                        // getContent() ; creates a new InputStream object of the entity.
                        // Now we need a readable source to read the byte stream that comes as the httpResponse
                        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                        // We have a byte stream. Next step is to convert it to a Character stream
                        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                        // Then we have to wraps the existing reader (InputStreamReader) and buffer the input
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                        // InputStreamReader contains a buffer of bytes read from the source stream and converts these into characters as needed.
                        //The buffer size is 8K
                        //Therefore we need a mechanism to append the separately coming chunks in to one String element
                        // We have to use a class that can handle modifiable sequence of characters for use in creating String
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                        String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                        // There may be so many buffered chunks. We have to go through each and every chunk of characters
                        //and assign a each chunk to bufferedStrChunk String variable
                        //and append that value one by one to the stringBuilder
                        while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                            stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                        }

                        // Now we have the whole response as a String value.
                        //We return that value then the onPostExecute() can handle the content
                        System.out.println("Returninge of doInBackground :" + stringBuilder.toString());

                        // If the Username and Password match, it will return "working" as response
                        // If the Username or Password wrong, it will return "invalid" as response
                        return stringBuilder.toString();

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                        System.out.println("Exceptionrates caz of httpResponse :" + cpe);
                        cpe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.out.println("Secondption generates caz of httpResponse :" + ioe);
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    System.out.println("httpResponse :" + result);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONArray login = jsonObject.getJSONArray("savepersonaldetails");
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = login.getJSONObject(0);
                        // edited second, you response was responsetype, but I parsed was responsetypes,so you can have a look.
                        String responsetypes = jsonObject1.optString("responsetype");
                        String message = jsonObject1.getString("message");

                        if (TextUtils.equals(responsetypes, "success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else if (TextUtils.equals(responsetypes, "failure")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Initialize the AsyncTask class
            HttpGetAsyncTask httpGetAsyncTask = new HttpGetAsyncTask();
    // Parameter we pass in the execute() method is relate to the first generic type of the AsyncTask
    // We are passing the connectWithHttpGet() method arguments to that
            httpGetAsyncTask.execute(firstname,lastname,emailid,password,birthdate,zipcode,sex,address,country,city,contactno,
                    height,weight,qualification,occupation,pye,dopinion,attendcourse, String.valueOf(userID));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                // action with ID action_refresh was selected
                case android.R.id.home:
                    Intent i8= new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
                    i8.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i8);
                    finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private boolean checkValidation() {
            boolean ret = true;

            if (!Validation.hasText(edFname)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.hasText(edPass)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.isEmailAddress(edEmail, true)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.isBirthDate(edBdate, true)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.hasText(edAddress)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.hasText(edCountry)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.hasText(edState)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.hasText(edCity)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.isPhoneNumber(edMob, true)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.hasText(edHeight)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.hasText(edWeight)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.hasText(edQualification)) ret = false;
            if (!Validation.hasText(edOccupation)) ret = false;

            return ret;
        }

        private void updateLabel() {
            String myFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
            edBdate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `httpGetAsyncTask.execute` call only passes 18  parameters whereas you are trying to get the 19th parameter in `String paramUserid = params[19];`. Hence the error. Check your execute call and pass more params.

**PS :** this is not an ideal way to pass data though. No method call should have 19 parameters. Create a model class of type User containing these 19 fields, and set the values in that model class and then pass it.